# When I started a new vue project, the browser gave me a mask layer error

Tags: vue.js, npm

I used "vue create vue" to create a directory of vue.
When I enter the directory (I didn't change any code),and use "npm run serve".
I use "http://localhost:8080" in the EDGE browser,and the mask layer error occur.
[the mask layer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVkh1.png)
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERu7B.png)

When I clicked the Close button in the top right corner, the page worked fine, but the problem continued after I refreshed it again.
How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: the plugin causing this